# React useForm equivalent in class component

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

I moved a functional component to class component recently and don't find the equivalent of `useForm` when using a class.
Here is the code I used before:

```js
var commentField = form.getState()["active"].replace(new RegExp("parameter_info$"), "comment");
form.change(commentField, result.comment);
```

With this, I was able to link two dynamicaly generated inputs.
How can I do it using a class?

Answer (score 0):

FinalForm docs says `useForm() is used internally inside useField(), <Field/>, and <FormSpy/>.`, so it's possible to write equivalent code using `FormSpy`:

```
  class Updater extends React.Component {
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      var commentField = this.props.form.getState()["active"].replace(new RegExp("parameter_info$"), "comment");
      this.props.form.change(commentField, result.comment);
    }
  
    render() {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

You need to render `<FormSpy subscription={{ values: true }} component={Updater} />` somewhere in your form to make it work.

Note that you can use `final-form-calculate` package to implement calculations between fields.